# Is ggplot2 for python via plotnine not supported anymore?

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot, plotnine

Eventhough I get a proper diagram (yeay!), I also get this warning each time I run ggplot:

```
FutureWarning: Attribute 'is_copy' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

I use Python 3.6 and:

```
from plotnine import * #Vers. 0.3.0
import pandas as pd #Vers. 0.23.1
from pandas import DataFrame
```

The ggplot code is:

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(x='date', y='meanDN')) + geom_point()
print(g)
```

**Should I be concerened?**

Comment: The warning will go away when the next version of plotnine ships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning comes from a call to the pandas library. plotnine still uses a functionality of pandas that has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Plotnine is actively developed, and this bug has been [fixed already](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/commit/9b068b458f4864e05927deab2f374c26b7a64cce).

There was no new release after plotnine 0.3.0 yet, so you will have to install the development version from GitHub or wait for a new release to make the warning go away.